# Найти точку на окружности зная координаты центра окружности, координаты второй точки и радиус

Tags: математика, вектор, координаты, векторы

Есть круг, зная координаты центра и радиус найти точку на окружности ближайшую ко второй точке вне зависимости от удаленности.

Координаты красных точек известны как и радиус, найти координаты зеленых точек. Формула?

Допустим координаты центра: 4,7
Радиус: 3
Красной точки: 9,14
См. скриншот для примера

Пробовал формулу:
координата х = 4 + (3 * cos(угол меджу точками))
координата у = 7 + (3 * sin(угол между точками))

Почти то что нужно, но есть зависимость от удаленности второй точки от центра круга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не пойму. Зеленые точки не на окружности. Какому условию они отвечают? Потом, угол нужен не между точками, а угол отрезка относительно прямой из центра, параллельной OX. И, кстати, в ваших формулах нет никакой зависимости от "удаленности второй точки от центра круга"...

Comment: Не понял. В вопросе "найти точку на окружности". На рисунке требуемые точки - не на окружности. Объяснения?

Comment: Просто не правильно нарисовал, под рукой не было рисовалки нормальной. На самом деле изменяя радиус можно контролировать удаленность зеленой точки от центра, это то что мне нужно, а в описании привязался к радиусу для объяснений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x0, y0 - center
x1, y1 - red dot
r - radius

x2, y2 - green dot - ?

d = sqrt((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1 - y0)**2)
x2 = x0 + (x1 - x0) / d * r
y2 = y0 + (y1 - y0) / d * r
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает!